# Image overlapping in sencha touch's carousel

Tags: css, sencha-touch, extjs, carousel

I created carousel which loads many images. However, each image is overlapping to another image from different card as shown here:
[image: card_1]   [image: card_2]   [image: card_3]

As you can see in the screenshot, some part of the first image appear in the second card and so on.

This is how I put the image inside a "html" component within carousel's item:

```
html: '<div> <img src="'+avaImg+'" />'
```

Is there any way to make the image fit into the screen regardless the resolution of the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`Ext.Image`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Img) component in Sencha Touch 2 ?

Then you can apply custom styling to that image using [`style`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Img-cfg-style) config.

Comment: I can't do that because there are some data (text) that I need to attach to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @tukang you can try to create css class, something like this,

```
.your_name {
   background-image: url(your_url_image);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

And after put it on your html tag `<div class="your_name"></div>`

**I hope help you. :)**

Comment: I think it's difficult to implement because I load the images using store iteration (dynamic images loading).